# Underbracket with long label

Tags: math-mode, formatting, brackets

I'm trying to do the same thing as the photo below
[image]

But the result that I get is pretty annoying (as you can see)
[image]

```
$P(E|F) = \frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(F)} = \frac{|E\cap F|}{|\Omega|}\cdot \frac{|\Omega|}{|F|} = \underbrace{\frac{|E\cap F|}{|F|}}_{\text{"casi favorevoli su casi possibili" su uno SP ridotto. Condizionare riduce lo spazio degli esiti possibili}} = \frac{3}{5}$
```

So my question is this: is there any way i can "wrap" the text below the bracket into something at least readable in a single row?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `\parbox{width}{text}` but I'd probably just use `(*)` and then explain `(*)` in the text below the equation. Adding massive amounts of text like this is not really a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest the label in a  `\parbox` of a sensible size and use the `clap`command from `mathtools`. Additionally, you might type the label in footnotesize.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ P(E\mid F) = \frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(F)} = \frac{|E\cap F|}{|\Omega|}\cdot \frac{|\Omega|}{|F|} = \underbrace{\frac{|E\cap F|}{|F|}}_{\clap{\parbox{6.5cm}{"casi favorevoli su casi possibili" su uno SP ridotto. Condizionare riduce lo spazio degli esiti possibili}}} = \frac{3}{5} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]